# Player Controller not working with rotation?

Tags: c#, unity, rotate

I have created a player character controller. It rotates first time good but not after rotate to its original position before rotation. I am sharing code with you so any one can help me, How can I rotate character controller to 60 on Z-axis and again back to 0 degree on Z-axis?

```
void Update()
{
    var inputDirection = inputDetector.DetectInputDirection();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        moveDirection.y = JumpSpeed;
        anim.SetBool ("RunToJump", true);
    } else {
        anim.SetBool ("RunToJump", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S) && controller.isGrounded) {                        
        anim.SetBool ("RunToSlip", true);
        controller.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 60);
        Invoke ("StopSlidding", 0.1f);
     } 
  }
   void StopSlidding(){
   anim.setbool("RunToSlip", false);
   controller.transform.Rotate(0,0,0);  
}
```

First `controller.transform.Rotate(0,0,60);` works fine but second time I invoke `StopSlidding` method `controller.transform.Rotate(0,0,60);` It doesn't work. So my player character controller remains same on Z-axis 60 degree. I want to rotate it again to Z-axis 0 degree. So Any one can help me on this problem? My player starts moving with game scene start so there are no matter about moving player. 
I am using `Controller.Move();` to move my player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are telling it to rotate by 60 on the Z axis, and then the 2nd time you are telling it to rotate by 0 (no change).

Either change your 2nd to (0, 0, -60) or use transform.rotation instead of transform.Rotate()

Comment: Yaah man, thanks i forget that or i can't  focus on that. thanks for help me